# ABAP "SET EXTENDED CHECK" statement inside class definition

Tags: abap

In a customer object, I see the following ABAP code:

```
CLASS lcl_detail DEFINITION FINAL.
  SET EXTENDED CHECK OFF.      
  PUBLIC SECTION.
  [...]
ENDCLASS.
```

I've performed a syntax check on an SAP 7.40 system and it is fine.  But if I check the 7.40 ABAP Keyword documentation of [CLASS DEFINITION](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_740/en/index.htm), it does not say that SET EXTENDED CHECK is allowed in this place.  Also, I though there shouldn't be anything between the CLASS DEFINITION part and the first SECTION part.

Comment: I wouldn't name `SET EXTENDED CHECK OFF.` a ABAP statement but a compiler statement (it does not change the report, but how errors are reported in the extended syntax check).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the `SET EXTENDED CHECK {ON|OFF}` statement is used to activate/deactivate the complete check of the ABAP source code for all errors that can be detected statically, it can be put in any section of a program.

It is not used in program's execution. It's used when you run the extended program check (SLIN or ABAP Test Cockpit).